# Align issues in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, alignment

New to Illustrator (cc) and having some issues making the align tool work for me. I am trying to place all pieces 1.5mm apart for a lasercutting file but when I use the align tool it causes them to either overlap or spread much farther than 1.5mm apart. I am too busy to manually measure the distance between hundreds of objects and play puzzle master; so I am really hoping someone can explain why my objects overlap/spread instead of placing themselves 1.5mm apart like I specify.

Thankyou in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Are you taking stroke into account? When does it overlap and when does it spread further, what do you do different? Can you [edit your question and add some screenshot](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/73955/edit)?

Answer (score 1):

The align only aligns based on bounding box. Not actually the shape of the object. So aligning a few random shapes wont have the specified separation the boxes surrounding them do.

[image]

**Image 1**: Align with spacing aligns the bounding boxes spaced by distance. Boxes in cyan.

Astute Graphics has made a tool called [ColliderScribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/) that can make this a bit faster though. Not optimal but at least much faster than doing in manually.

**A side note**: Laying out stuff for optimal layout is indeed a NP-hard problem its actually a variant of [the traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). And it can not be solved efficiently if it could it would have a tremendous impact on many industries.